# Backbone.js template does not inherit attributes from model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get a simple SPA going for testing purposes with Backbone. When I render my view, my Underscore template is not inheriting any attributes from my model. I'm going to assume that I'm making a simple mistake but after fiddling with it for over an hour I am seeking some guidance here. If it helps, I am using ASP.NET Web API 2, jQuery 2.x+, and the latest versions of Backbone and Underscore.

My template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="equipmentTemplate">
    <td><%= ID %></td>
    <td><%= Name %></td>
    <td><%= Quantity %></td>
    <td><%= Description %></td>
</script>
```

My code:

```
// Single item model
var EquipmentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/equipment',
    defaults: {
        ID: '',
        Name: '',
        Quantity: '',
        Description: ''
    },
});

// Collection of our single item models
var EquipmentList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: EquipmentModel,
    url: '/api/equipment'
});

// GET single instance of model
var equipmentModel = new EquipmentModel({ id: 1 });
equipmentModel.fetch();

// GET entire collection
var equipmentList = new EquipmentList();
equipmentList.fetch();

// Create single model view
EquipmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: _.template($("#equipmentTemplate").html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    }
});
var equipmentView = new EquipmentView({ model: equipmentModel });
equipmentView.render();
```

When running `console.log(equipment.fetch())` is called, the following is returned from the server:

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Object
responseText: "{"ID":1,"Name":"A random part","Quantity":2,"Description":"foo bar approved."}"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

However, when I return the view's el, I see:

```
equipmentView.$el.html()
"
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
"
```

Also, to note, I have tried to include an actual model in the View and the items do not render. I have also tried using `this.model.toJSON()`. One example of what I've tried is:

```
EquipmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: _.template($("#equipmentTemplate").html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html('<td>'+ this.model.get('Name') + '</td>');
    }
});
```

Yet, that just yields an empty `<td></td>` ...which doesn't seem right.

Update: 
Got it, thanks to gerl.

I needed to fetch the model inside of the view:

```
// Create single model view
EquipmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.fetch();
    },
    tagName: "tr",
    template: _.template($("#equipmentTemplate").html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
var equipmentView = new EquipmentView({ model: equipmentModel });
equipmentView.render();
```

And that worked.

Comment: Try to add default values in your model attributes like defaults: {
        ID: 1,
        Name: 'bob'...
    }, and see if it'll print. Also you can add your fetch call inside initialize in the collection. Like initialize: function() {
   this.fetch();
  }

Comment: It did - for example: var EquipmentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/equipment',
    defaults: {
        ID: 42,
        Name: 'gerlTest',
        Quantity: 12,
        Description: 'Testing'
    },
}); returned     <td>42</td>
    <td>gerlTest</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Testing</td> ... I suppose I'm a little confused as even with the default values in, when I call the instance of the model .toJSON() it still returns the data fetched from the server. However, I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Alright - so throwing the this.model.fetch() inside of initialize worked it out. Would you mind throwing that up as an answer so I can accept it and give you points?

Comment: No problem. Here you go.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the fetch call in your model or collection (whichever one calls from json).

Something like:

```
var EquipmentList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: EquipmentModel,
    url: '/api/equipment',
    initialize: function() { 
      this.fetch(); 
    }
});
```